# Protection for/protection of

Tags: prepositions

> People have the right to demand protection ___ their business against a bandit group trying to grab it.

I see both *of* and *for* being used with *protection*. Although in many sentences it's clear to judge which preposition *sounds* better but in the above sentence both *of* and *for* sound correct,so I am not able to decide which preposition is to be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, either sounds fine.  I prefer *for*, but it's a question of style not grammar.

However you can avoid the dilemma by restructuring the sentence:

> People have a right to demand their businesses be protected **from** extortion by a bandit group operating in that area.

Comment: I would prefer *for* because it indicates purpose, as in "I will buy tools *for* my business."